# How to map a RDD to another RDD with Scala, in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD:

```
RDD1 = (big,data), (apache,spark), (scala,language) ...
```

and I need to map that with the time stamp

```
RDD2 = ('2015-01-01 13.00.00')
```

so that I get

```
RDD3 = (big, data, 2015-01-01 13.00.00), (apache, spark, 2015-01-01 13.00.00), (scala, language, 2015-01-01 13.00.00)
```

I wrote a simple `map` function for this:

```
RDD3 = RDD1.map(rdd => (rdd, RDD2))
```

but it is not working, and I think it is not the way to go.
How to do it? I am new to Scala and Spark. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to add the same timestamp to all elements in `RDD1`? What is the type of the `RDD2`?

Comment: I am generating tweet word pairs from Twitter4j stauses and for each tweet word pair wanted to add time stamp of that tweet status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(("big","data") :: ("apache","spark") :: ("scala","language") :: Nil)
// RDD[(String, String)]
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(List.fill(3)(new java.util.Date().toString))
// RDD[String]

rdd1.zip(rdd2).map{ case ((a,b),c) => (a,b,c) }.collect()
// Array((big,data,Fri Jul 24 22:25:01 CEST 2015), (apache,spark,Fri Jul 24 22:25:01 CEST 2015), (scala,language,Fri Jul 24 22:25:01 CEST 2015))
```

If you want the same time stamp with every element of `rdd1` :

```
val now = new java.util.Date().toString
rdd1.map{ case (a,b) => (a,b,now) }.collect()
```